# How to change subplot title after creation in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

With matplotlib I could do this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

axs[0].bar(x=[0,1,2], height=[1,2,3])
axs[1].plot(np.random.randint(1, 10, 50))

axs[0].set_title('BARPLOT')
axs[1].set_title('WOLOLO')
```

[image]

With plotly I know only one way to set subplot titles -- at the creation:
`fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=('title1', 'title2'))`

Is it possible to set subplots title after creation?
Maybe, through getting access to original `Axes` class of matplotlib (I read that plotly.python based on seaborn which is based on matplotlib)?
Or through `fig.layout`?

Please use this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y=[1, 2, 3]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=np.random.randint(1, 10, 50)), row=1, col=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following code does the trick you want.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2"))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(y=[1, 2, 3]), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=np.random.randint(1, 10, 50)), row=1, col=2)

fig.layout.annotations[1].update(text="Stackoverflow")

fig.show()
```

I got this idea from https://community.plotly.com/t/subplot-title-alignment/33210/2 when it's described how to access each plot's annotation.

Comment: So, basically, we need to specify initial subtitles as placeholders, and then we will be able to iterate over and change them. Thx!